# Mongoid - two query conditions to both be met in an embedded doc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have two models

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :username
   embeds_many :user_tags
end

class UserTag
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  field :like_count, :type => Integer, :default => 0
  embedded_in :user
end
```

I want to query all the users that have the user_tag named "nyc" and where the user_tag "nyc" has a like_count > 10.  I've tried the following:

```
users = User.where('user_tags.name' => "nyc").and('user_tags.like_count' => {'$gte' => 10 })
```

Logically this does what it's supposed to do, but not what I need it to do.  It returns users that have the user_tag "nyc" and have any user_tag with a like_count >= 10.  I need users that have the user_tag "nyc" and where the user_tag "nyc"'s like_count is >= 10.

How do I do that?  I'm running mongoid 4.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your query is not correct for the purpose you are trying to achieve. It translates to the following MongoDB query:

```
db.users.find({'user_tags.name': 'nyc' }, {'user_tags.like_count': {$gte: 10}})
```

It means that MongoDB will find all documents with both criteria. Mongoid is returning you the same data, as MongoDB.

What you need instead is the following MongoDB query:

```
db.users.find({ user_tags: {
  $elemMatch: {
    name: 'nyc',
    like_count: { $gte: 10  }
  }
}})
```

With Mongoid you can write:

```
User.where(user_tags: {
  '$elemMatch' => {
    name: 'nyc',
    like_count: { '$gte' => 10 }
  }
}).count
```

Comment: Yes, @dimakura, this worked as expected.  Thank you.  Is there a way I can chain an order by to this query?  I'd like to order by like_count, but this doesn't seem to work:  users = User.where(user_tags: {'$elemMatch' => {name: 'nyc', like_count: { '$gte' => 10 }}, }).order_by(:'user_tags.like_count' => desc)

Comment: @aressidi there are `asc`, `desc` methods, also `sort` and `order_by`. You should use them like this though: `condition.order_by(field: 1)` for ascending, and `condition.order_by(field: -1)` for descending orders.

Comment: Hi @dimakura, thanks again for your prompt reply.  Can you put the pieces together for me?  I've tried a number of different combos to get this to work.  How would I get the order_by working for like_count in the Mongoid example you provided above?  When i use the 1 or -1 to specify sort order, the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should write something like this:

```
users = User.where('user_tags.name' => "nyc", 'user_tags.like_count' => {'$gte' => 10 })
```

Mongoid will try to find Documents which satisfies both conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
users = User.where('user_tags.name' => "nyc").where('user_tags.like_count' => {'$gte' => 10 }).all
```

or

```
users = User.where('user_tags.name' => "nyc", 'user_tags.like_count' => {'$gte' => 10 }).all
```